# How to fix this problem with Q# installation: "Preparing Q# environment... Access to the path 'C:\Users\Sanjiv\Application Data' is denied."

Tags: python, quantum-computing, q#

I installed Q# with Python as per the instructions on Microsoft's site.  Then, I tested the installation.   It ran fine the first time.  But subsequently, when I try to run any program, I get the message:
Preparing Q# environment...
Access to the path 'C:\Users\Sanjiv\Application Data' is denied.
Then it waits for a while and then I get the message:
Exception:  Q# environment was not available in allocated time.

I have tried the following:  1.  Changing ownership of C:\Users\Sanjiv and its subdirectories to myself. 2. Running the command window as admin.

I don't know what else to try to fix this problem.

Comment: What error comes up when running it as admin. It shouldn't show the access denied error.

Comment: It gives the same, "access denied" error

Answer (score 0):

> Application Data is not an actual folder, it is a Junction which is
>   only there for backward compatibility. A Junction is a shortcut that
>   redirects files and programs to a different location.
>
> This particular Junction points to the 
>   `C:Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming` folder.
>
> There is a good explanation of Junction Points at the following
>   website.
>
> http://www.svrops.com/svrops/articles/jpoints.htm

[source](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/92448-access-got-denied-in-c-users-username-application-data-for-win7-and-vista)

Comment: I also changed the ownership of C:Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming folder to myself.  It still continues to give the same error.

Comment: That's not my code.  This is Microsoft provided software.  So I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a little late for the original poster, but in case anyone else runs across this issue, there is a workaround discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/149).

Basically it seems to be related to your Q# `.ipynb` notebook file living in your user profile folder, alongside the `Application Data` folder which for some reason is inaccessible in your file system.

You should be able to workaround this issue by creating/opening your Q# `.ipynb` notebook files from any other folder on your disk.